# OpenTBS Excel number format

Tags: php, excel, opentbs

I'm trying to format numbers in an Excel file using PHP and opentbs.

Here's template code I'm working from:

```
[gross_pay_names;block=begin;sub1=departments][gross_pay_names.name]
[gross_pay_names_sub1;block=begin]
[gross_pay_names_sub1.val; ope=tbs:num] 
[gross_pay_names_sub1;block=end]
[gross_pay_names;block=end]
```

The problem is in the third line:

```
[gross_pay_names_sub1.val; ope=tbs:num]
```

It always renders with an apostrophe in the beginning ('0.00). So I can't use it in other formulas in the file.

Comment: You should also state what you want to achieve, e.g. "not having an apostrophe ever"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solutions myself. In case anybody needs it in the future here's the template code I ended up using:

```
[gross_pay_names.name;block=tbs:row;sub1=departments]   [gross_pay_names_sub1.val;block=tbs:cell;ope=tbs:num]
```